# How to join two tables with another table

Tags: sql

I have three tables as pf ,pm and s.i have succesfully joined table pf and pm.but i am struggling when i try to join table s for these two tables.

table pf contains - style,color,meter,yard,kilo,grn_no and tag_gen

table pm contains - date, customer_id, gp_no

i have join these two tables using pm.go_no and pf.grn_no.it works.
Now i am trying to join s table to this.

table s contains -  customer_id, style, color and unit_qty

So what i wants to do is i want to get Unit_qty which matches pf tables style ,color and pm tables customer_id.

Here is my code

```
SELECT pm.date, pm.customer, pf.style, pf.color, s.unit_qty, COUNT(pf.roll_no) AS Roll_QTY, SUM(pf.yard) AS Yard_QTY, SUM(pf.meter) AS Meter_QTY, SUM(pf.kilo) AS Kilo_QTY, SUM( case when pf.aql_status = 0  then pf.meter else 0 end ) FB_Not_Passed_Qty, SUM( case when pf.aql_status = 1 and  pf.tag_gen = 0  then pf.meter else 0 end ) Not_Planned_Qty 
FROM packinglists_main pm, packinglists_fabrics_items pf, style_data s 
WHERE pf.grn_no= pm.gp_no[ AND pm.date BETWEEN {DateR,RANGE1} AND {DateR,RANGE2}][ AND s.style = pf.style][ AND s.color = pf.color][ AND s.customer_id = pm.customer_id] 
GROUP BY pm.customer, pf.style, pf.color
```

Comment: (1) I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please tag appropriately and add the tag for the database you are really using.  (2) Learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Read up on proper JOIN syntax. The joins you have are old and archaic and should not be used in current standards.

Comment: What do the curly and square brackets mean? Product specific?

Comment: @jarlih im using this query generate a report using reporting tool.it wants those brackets.i wants to know whether this query is fine to output the unit_qty?

Answer (score 0):

This will return all the columns from your three tables. Do whatever you want to do with them

```
SELECT * from pf 
INNER JOIN pm on pf.grn_no = pm.gp_no 
INNER JOIN s on s.style = pf.style
       AND s.Color = pf.Color 
       AND s.CustomerID = pm.CustomerID
```